# Check added custom fields in odoo

Tags: odoo

Is there an easy way to compare to odoo (SaaS version) databases/instances in terms of added/changed custom fields?

Downloading databases gigabytes of database dumps and try to compare there seems to be to much effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the `ir_model_fields` table.
For example :

```sql
select * from ir_model_fields where model='stock.picking';
```

```
+----+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+-----------------+----+--------+---------+-----+-------------------+--------+--------+-----+---------+----+-----+---------+------+----------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+----------------+
|id  |name    |complete_name|model        |relation         |relation_field|model_id|field_description|help|ttype   |selection|copy |related            |required|readonly|index|translate|size|state|on_delete|domain|selectable|relation_table|column1|column2|compute|depends|store|create_uid|create_date|write_uid|write_date|serialization_field_id|track_visibility|
+----+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+-----------------+----+--------+---------+-----+-------------------+--------+--------+-----+---------+----+-----+---------+------+----------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+----------------+
|5709|name    |NULL         |stock.picking|NULL             |NULL          |335     |Reference        |NULL|char    |NULL     |false|NULL               |false   |false   |true |false    |NULL|base |NULL     |NULL  |true      |NULL          |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |true |NULL      |NULL       |NULL     |NULL      |NULL                  |NULL            |
|5715|group_id|NULL         |stock.picking|procurement.group|NULL          |335     |Procurement Group|NULL|many2one|NULL     |false|move_lines.group_id|false   |true    |false|false    |NULL|base |set null |NULL  |true      |NULL          |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |true |NULL      |NULL       |NULL     |NULL      |NULL                  |NULL            |
+----+--------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+-----------------+----+--------+---------+-----+-------------------+--------+--------+-----+---------+----+-----+---------+------+----------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------+----------------+
```